How can I import my modules, which defined in notebook-dir path, from notebook located in sub-directories
PyCharm somehow open notebook files with such environment, that executing notebook from different sub directories will correctly import my module, located in root directory.
But when I try to setup server myself and try to execute notebook, I will got error that state my_module is not find.
How can I setup server/environment in that way that I can import my module, located in root directory (notebook-dir) and successfully execute notebook files?

do you have a jupyter_notebook_config.py file?

sys.path.append ?

@DiptangsuGoswami Its true, if I add my root directory to path via sys.path.append, notebook will correctly import my module. But right now I need add such line in notebook, can I smh configured jupyter server/enviroment in such way that I don't need to add such line in code?
